Check if a List has a property and if the list does format another field in the list in C#
So I am newer to C#. I have mainly worked in Javascript. I wan to check and see if a list of items contains items that has a property of isOpen set to true. I then want to use this new list of isOpen items and set another property to a formatted address. For some reason this doesn't seem to take. Here is what I have tried.:
 var isOpen = inventory.Inventory.Where(i => i.IsOpen).ToList();

if (isOpen.Any())
{
    foreach (var inventoryItem in isOpen)
    {
        inventoryItem.Address1 = FormatAddress(inventoryItem.Address1);
        inventoryItem.Address2 = FormatAddress(inventoryItem.Address2);
    }
}

Also, here is the formatter:
private string FormatAddress(string address)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address))
     {
         return "";
     }

     TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
     string formattedAddress = textInfo.ToTitleCase(address);
     return formattedAddress;
 }

Any help is appreciated!

"use this new list", but you used the original list.

Shouldn't inventoryItem be on isOpen and not inventory.Inventory?

Ah crap. That is my bad, I should have just copied over what I was doing. I will update my code.

As an aside, if (isOpen.Any()) is superfluous, because the foreach will account for that anyway.

@JohnathanBarclay That makes a lot of sense. Don't know how I missed that.

Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ih6FsD

Complete your example with instances that don't behave as you wish, and show the result. Because right now the code you're showing should follow what you're describing.

Hey guys, thanks for the help. Turns out there was a bug that was breaking it caused by something else. After reviewing @JohnathanBarclay fiddle, I was able to realize that. Thanks again and sorry for wasting your guys time.

Use ToTitleCase with caution.  I live in Oregon where it is common to use compass directions in street names.  An input address of "101 third ave ne" would return "101 Third Ave Ne" as title case, but the preferred output should be "101 Third Ave NE".
